# Cookie issue in CURL (PHP) - Cookie information not attached in CURL headers

Tags: php, curl, cookies, header

I have this code

```
<?php
    $mLoginUrl = "https://www.test.com/login";
    $mCookieFile = dirname(__FILE__).'/tmpCookies/cookie'.rand().'.txt';

    define('USER_AGENT', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.2309.372 Safari/537.36');
    define('COOKIE_FILE', $mCookieFile);
    define('LOGIN_FORM_URL', $mLoginUrl);
    define('LOGIN_ACTION_URL', $mLoginUrl);

    $postValues = array(
        'user[email]' => "mymail@email.com",
        'user[password]' => "mypassword"
    );

    $headers = Array(
                "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5",
                "Cache-Control: max-age=0",
                "Connection: keep-alive",
                "Keep-Alive: 300",
                "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7",
                "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5",
                "Pragma: "
            );

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, LOGIN_ACTION_URL);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postValues));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,FALSE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, COOKIE_FILE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, COOKIE_FILE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, USER_AGENT);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, LOGIN_FORM_URL);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers) ;
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, TRUE);
    $res = curl_exec($curl);
    $info = curl_getinfo($curl);
    print_r($info['request_header']);
    exit;
?>
```

This works fine on my local computer and one of my servers and shows following output

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.2309.372 Safari/537.36
Host: www.test.com
Referer: https://www.test.com/login
Cookie: _property_session=WjROWEYvTHNYaE5Zb29jVk04WGM0Z3FybmhmY1ZIeVdBc2N6d2N3UmViaXlZdFNhR1dSbUN4QVh6aFFSRjFPYktybmdnRGlXNG0yWWcremEzcklKTnE1ZE1lTTM0eUQrSG90SVhRRzhvYW5rWmFQTVhBMjVCWjBtb1FSc0RrTEh2RjhHSFI3aHkwa3U4N3Y3czJhTzJuN2ZGbWRRN0Nra2Z6OTR4aHhvVG42bVVRS3kwTExUL1hMN2JoZ0xRd2g3VVdIMC81cGhLQzJjOTJvc2RYajIwakE0VjZqRnhTeHBleFltTGF4Z3hpUGJEb0E3Nlo2S3BwMElqNnVkaWhDVS0tc0pCRlozSVE5bXRHQXlHWE1IbTl4UT09--67cf6e056b84b4cae4d275507f544927802eb78d
Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Connection: keep-aliveKeep-Alive: 300 Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7 Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
```

which means that cookie was created and attached in headers of CURL (as we can see in above header print of CURL.) The cookie file is created as well at mentioned location.

But on one of my server the code do not work as per expectations and gives following output

```
POST /users/sign_in? HTTP/1.1 User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.2309.372 Safari/537.36 Host: www.test.com Referer: https://www.test.com/login Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5 Cache-Control: max-age=0 Connection: keep-alive Keep-Alive: 300 Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7 Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5 Content-Length: 76 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Means cookie information is not attached in headers of CURL. I have checked that cookie file is created in this (problematic) server too and is having cookie contents but still cookie contents are not included in CURL headers. Temporary cookie directory mentioned is having full rights/permissions (777) for all users.

PHP version is 5.4.19 and CURL version is 7.19.7 on problematic server.

If anybody can help? I have tried all of the solutions found on internet.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By mentioning the static file name as suggested by CatalinB I am able to get the Cookie information in headers, but still I am unable to login to other website. There is a little difference in result though. There is **POST /login?** in start instead of **GET**. 
This can be noted in my main question too that one is having GET and other is having POST. Why this is so? Any help? Please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for your help. I have solved issue. The issue was open_basedir path. I set this to "none" on server which fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`$mCookieFile = dirname(__FILE__).'/tmpCookies/cookie'.rand().'.txt';`

remove rand() ... to be a static file

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I mean now Cookie information is attached after mentioning the static file name, but still I am unable to login to other website. There is a little difference in result though. There is **POST /login?** in start instead of **GET**. 
This can be noted in my main question too that one is having GET and other is having POST. Why this is so? Any help? Please

Comment: you code make a post request and try to make a login from chrome and see in Chrome - Inspect -> Network what parameters are sent

Comment: I have uploaded the Chrome->Inspect->Network to following image. See if you can help. Why one is GET and other is POST if code is same? And GET is working http://imgur.com/a/Tfeka